# Pointer's weird behavior

Tags: c, pointers

Trying to run this piece of code:

```
void print_matrix(matrix* arg)
{
     int i, j;
     for(i = 0; i < arg->rows; i++) {
         for(j = 0; j < arg->columns; j++) {          // gdb shows, that arg->columns value
             printf("\n %f", arg->data[i][j]);        // has been changed in this line (was 
         }                                            // 3, is 0)
         printf("\n");
     }
}
```

`matrix` is a structure:

```
typedef struct matrix_t 
{
    int rows;
    int columns;
    double** data;

} matrix;
```

arg is properly allocated 3x3 matrix, rows = 3, columns = 3

Function does print only \n's .

Compiler is gcc 4.5.
Any ideas?

EDIT:

```
int main()
{
    matrix arg;
    arg.rows = 3;
    arg.columns = 3;
    arg.data = (double**)malloc(sizeof(double*) * arg.rows);
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < arg.rows; i++) {
       arg.data[i] = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double) * arg.columns);
    }

    arg.data[0][0] = 1; 
    arg.data[0][1] = 2;
    //......
    print_matrix(&arg);


    for(i = 0; i < arg.rows; i++) {
        free(arg.data[i]);
    }
    free(arg.data);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: How did you allocate and populate `data`? Why is `data` declared to be a pointer to a pointer?

Comment: Please post a [complete code sample](http://sscce.org/). Incomplete samples, when fleshed out by others, may not demonstrate the same behavior you're experiencing.

Comment: Copy-pasted code here : http://ideone.com/SoyQH . Seems to work as expected. What's the question again?

Comment: @Shawn Chin: That's interesting. print_matrix does not print matrix properly. Debugger shows that arg->columns value changes in line with second for - loop. Looks like code works as it should. I'll try to figure this out.

Comment: How do you build this code? Do you get any compiler warnings, and do you see the same error both with and without optimizations enabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments above, there seems to be *nothing wrong with the code*. Works fine when compiled on my machine and on IDEone. See http://ideone.com/SoyQH

I had a few minutes to spare, so I ran a few extra checks. These are pretty much the steps I take before each code commit or when I need some hints when debugging.

#### Testing with strict compiler flags

Compiling with gcc using `-Wall -pedantic` there were some warnings regarding ISO C90 incompatibilities but no show stoppers.

```
[me@home]$ gcc -Wall -pedantic -g k.c
k.c:17:55: warning: C++ style comments are not allowed in ISO C90
k.c:17:55: warning: (this will be reported only once per input file)
k.c: In function `main':
k.c:30: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code
```

Warnings related to :

- use of C++ style comments, i.e. `//` instead of `/* ... */`
- in `main()`, declaration of `int i;` was mixed in with code. C90 expects all declarations to be done at the beginning.

#### Using split

After addressing the above warnings, ran `splint -weak` on the code.

```
[me@home]$ splint -weak k.c
Splint 3.1.1 --- 15 Jun 2004

Finished checking --- no warnings
```

Nothing to report.

#### Valgrind

Valgrind confirms that there are no memory leaks but complains about the use of unitialised values in `printf` (not all elements in `args->data` were given values).

```
[me@home]$ valgrind ./a.out
==5148== Memcheck, a memory error detector.
... <snip> ...
==5148==

 1.000000
 2.000000
==5148== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5148==    at 0x63D6EC: __printf_fp (in /lib/tls/libc-2.3.4.so)
==5148==    by 0x63A6C4: vfprintf (in /lib/tls/libc-2.3.4.so)
==5148==    by 0x641DBF: printf (in /lib/tls/libc-2.3.4.so)
==5148==    by 0x804842A: print_matrix (k.c:18)
==5148==    by 0x8048562: main (k.c:42)
... <snip> ...
==5148==
==5148== ERROR SUMMARY: 135 errors from 15 contexts (suppressed: 12 from 1)
==5148== malloc/free: in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks.
==5148== malloc/free: 4 allocs, 4 frees, 84 bytes allocated.
==5148== For counts of detected errors, rerun with: -v
==5148== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible.
```

### Conclusion

Nothing to report. Moving on.

Answer (score 1):

`matrix.data` is a wild pointer. You need to allocate memory for the matrix and make `data` point to it.

Comment: OP : `arg is properly allocated 3x3 matrix, rows = 3, columns = 3`

Comment: @Aviral: anyone who needs to ask on SO what's going wrong with this code can't be trusted to make such a statement....